# Execute if else condition parallelly over list of strings

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, regex

I'm new in python and facing an issue in getting the right output. I have a list of strings as :

```
list_string=[
    '!DOC <p>The course starts next Sunday</t><div>',
    "!DOC <p>class='default'<d>I don't wash the dishes</span></t>",
    'When does the train usually leave'
]
```

All I want output as:

```
Output expected: [['The course starts next Sunday'], ["I don't wash the dishes"], 'When does the train usually leave']
```

What I've done is something:

```
import re
subtring='!DOC'
output=[]
for i in string:
    if subtring in i:
        text=re.findall("<p>(.*?)</t>",i, re.DOTALL)
        output.append(text)
    elif subtring in i:
        text=re.findall("<d>(.*?)</span>",i, re.DOTALL)
        output.append(text)
    else:
        output.append(i)
print (output)

[['The course starts next Sunday'], ["class='default'<d>I don't wash the dishes</span>"], 'When does the train usually leave']
```

Can anyone suggest the right way to do it?

Comment: Why do you have two `subtring in i` tests? The second one will never succeed.

Comment: Why should the second string be processed with the second regexp instead of the first one?

Comment: Do both in the same `if` block.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. The second string matches both regular expressions. Why should the output contain the result from the 2nd `findall` instead of the 1st one?

Comment: How does one know to exclude `class='default'` from the result?

Comment: @JonSG that's what second condition represents. I want text in between tags <d> and </span>

Comment: Oh, so you want the text between specific landmarks in your array of strings that just happen to look a bit like html and not simply the text nodes of your given html?  Right?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the second rule trumps the first so if there is a match on the second rule, use it otherwise try the first rule falling back to returning what you were given.

A solution that is close to what you have now might be:

```
import re

list_string =[
    '!DOC <p>The course starts next Sunday</t><div>',
    "!DOC <p>class='default'<d>I don't wash the dishes</span></t>",
    'When does the train usually leave'
]

output=[]
for line in list_string:
    retval = re.findall("<d>(.*?)</span>", line,  re.DOTALL)
    if retval:
        output.append(retval[0])
        continue

    retval = re.findall("<p>(.*?)</t>", line,  re.DOTALL)
    if retval:
        output.append(retval[0])
        continue

    output.append(line)

print (output)
```

Though if it was me, I would probably use a little function with a comprehension:

```
import re

def pick_out_text(text):
    retval = re.findall("<d>(.*?)</span>", text,  re.DOTALL)
    if retval: return retval[0]

    retval = re.findall("<p>(.*?)</t>", text, re.DOTALL)
    if retval: return retval[0]

    return text

list_string =[
    '!DOC <p>The course starts next Sunday</t><div>',
    "!DOC <p>class='default'<d>I don't wash the dishes</span></t>",
    'When does the train usually leave'
]

output = [pick_out_text(line) for line in list_string]

print(output)
```